# How to publish individual HTML report in Hudson per job run

Tags: jenkins, hudson, hudson-api

I have a parameterized Hudson job that generates HTML report as a result.
I need to attach this HTML to the build **NOT to the job** as HTML report changes based on the parameters.
http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/HTML+Publisher+Plugin did not help because it attaches report to the job and shows the HTML report from the latest build.
Is there any way to attach HTMl report to the build that with hudson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way: [Sidebar Link Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sidebar-Link+Plugin) . Generate anything you want, deploy it anywhere ( Jenkins private files, which can then be accessed via http (described on plugin page at comments section) / some other http server ) and use the mentioned plugin to create a linked link for each job that will direct the clicker to html.

You will need to add a post-build action in the job called 'Anchor chain' that will contained ( described on plugin page )  parameters which will be used to create additional sidebar link.

Comment: Thank You Jan.
This could work.
But, my main requirement is something similar to what HTML+Publisher+Plugin does. 
It should store the HTML data(html and supporting files) and add a link to it in the build. Its not preferrable to store the data somewhere else and use that link in my current requirement.

Comment: Have you tried to check the check box 'Keep past html reports'  in HTML publisher? It is described on plugin page. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin

Comment: Yes, it is working.
It was working all along,I did not notice.
Thank you.

Comment: That happens sometimes too :) Glad you've solved that.

Answer (score 4):

By default the [HTML Publisher plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/htmlpublisher) only saves the most recent report on the job. If you want a report for each individual run saved, do the following:

In your HTML Publisher configuration, click on *"Publishing options"*, and select *"Keep past HTML reports"*.

It should now save the report for the most recent job **and** also save the report for each individual run.